# Swagger oauth access token and refresh token implementation for api endpoints

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

There are some api endpoints which need access token in authorization header. I am looking for a way where Some endpoints need access token in header. Such endpoints have a button for authroization and clicking on that button, it should hit oauth endpoint and generate access token and refresh token. That access token should automatically added in header for such request and proceed request. If access token is expired then it should generate access token by saved refresh token. I belive i have to use both security definitions

```
securityDefinitions:
      sample_auth:
       type: oauth2
       authorizationUrl: http://<auhtorizeationUrl>
       tokenUrl: http://<tokenUrl>
       flow: accessCode
       scopes:
        write: "modify sample  in your account"  

     sample_api_key:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: Authorization
```

My project is in node.js. As a first step, I am trying with hardcoding access token in header with sample_api_key security using in my endpoint. I following code in swagger-ui index.html

```
function addApiKeyAuthorization(){
  console.log('key ');
    var key = encodeURIComponent( $('.input_apiKey_entry')[0].value );
    console.log('key '+key);
    if(key && key.trim() != "") {
        var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization( "Authorization", "Bearer " + key, "header" );
        window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add( "sample_api_key", apiKeyAuth );
        log( "Set bearer token: " + key );
    }
  }

   $('.input_apiKey_entry').change(addApiKeyAuthorization);
```

and added in my swagger.yaml in that specific endpoint 
    security: 
      - sample_api_key: []

In swagger ui, It provides me Authorize button clicking on it provide me option of adding Authroization value in text field. After authroizing, trigger request send error that 
    {
  "message": "unknown security handler: sample_api_key",
  "code": "server_error",
  "statusCode": 403
}

node.js code shows error of
    Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
    at applyHeaders (/Volumes/Data/samplegit/sample-api/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:146:15)
    at applyHeaders (/Volumes/Data/samplegit/sample-api/node_modules/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:142:11)
    at applyHeaders (/Volumes/Data/samplegit/sample-api/node_modules/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:142:11)